# The method of Lagrange's Multipliers

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I used the method of Lagrange's multpliers to find the maximum of $f(x,y,z)=\ln x+\ln y+3\ln z$ on the portion of the sphere $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=5r^2 \ ; r>0$ where $x>0, y>0, z>0$ .

I found that the  point $(r,r,\sqrt 3r)$ satisfies in the system  $\nabla f(x,y,z)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y,z),\ g(x,y,z)=5r^2$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$ uniquely, (Of course $\lambda=\frac{1}{2r^2}$).

Consequently, $f(r,r,\sqrt 3r)=\ln(3\sqrt3r^5)$ is only value of the solution of system.

My question is that why $\ln(3\sqrt3r^5)$ is maximum $f$ on $g=5r^2$ on the first octant.

How do I prove it algebraically?

Comment: Typo: It should be $g(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - 5r^2$ in the second paragraph. Also is your question: how to prove the maximum *without* using Lagrange's method (since you have basically proven then maximum with Lagrange's method)?

Comment: It is important that why $\ln(3\sqrt 3r^5)$ is the maximum value.

Comment: Apposed to a minimum? There is only one stationary point so a simple check of this is to calcuate another point satisfying the constraint and compare. For example $x=\sqrt{2}r,y=r\sqrt{2},z=r$ is on the sphere and $f = \log(2r^5) < \log(3\sqrt{3}r^5)$ so your point is a maximum.

Comment: I do not convinced with your explanation.

Comment: The function $f$ is bounded from above (on the sphere: $x,y,z\leq \sqrt{5}\to f < \log(\sqrt{5}^5r^5)$ ) so there has to exist a maximum. You have found only one extremal point so this has to be that maximum.

Comment: @Winther: the domain of $f$ is not the sphere, but a _non-compact_ subset. Therefore, this function, although bounded, might have no maximum.

Comment: @Circonflexe In general this is true. Here we have $f\to -\infty$ at the boundary points so the maximum is indeed taken on the interior.

Answer (score 1):

First thing first: you can simplify that $r$ out of the problem since it is homogeneous (but I would keep the $5$ since it does simplify the problem).
Second thing: $f(x) = \ln x + \ln y + 3 \ln z = \ln (xyz^3)$, and $\ln$ is monotonic, so you should discard it.

As Winther said, this is the only stationary point. Your octant is border-less and therefore non-compact: therefore, functions on it do  not necessarily have a maximum, and may even be unbounded. But if you can prove that $xyz^3$ has a maximum on the "octisphere", then this maximum is a critical point, of which there is only one, $(1,1,\sqrt{3})$.

You can do this by cutting the octisphere. For fixed $z$, it is easy to see that, for $x^2 + y^2 = 5-z^2$, $xy$ is maximal for $x = y = \sqrt{(5-z^2)/2}$, the maximal value then being $xy = (5-z^2)/2$. Now it is a simple exercise to check that $z^3 (5-z^2)/2$ does have a maximum on $]0,1]$, and even to find it.